# Bash: extract (percent) number of variable length from a string

Tags: string, bash, numbers, progress-bar

I want to write a little progress bar using a bash script.

To generate the progress bar I have to extract the progress from a log file.

The content of such a file (here run.log) looks like this:

> Time to finish  2d 15h,   42.5% completed, time steps left  231856

I'm now intersted to isolate the 42.5%. The problem is now that the length of this digit is variable as well as the position of the number (e.g. 'time to finish' might content only one number like 23h or 59min).

I tried it over the position via

```
echo "$(tail -1 run.log | awk '{print $6}'| sed -e 's/[%]//g')"
```

which fails for short 'Time to finish' as well as via the %-sign

```
echo "$(tail -1 run.log | egrep -o '[0-9][0-9].[0-9]%')"
```

Here is works only for digits >= 10%.

Any solution for a more variable nuumber extraction?

======================================================

Update: Here is now the full script for the progress bar:

```
#!/bin/bash

# extract % complete from run.log
perc="$(tail -1 run.log | grep -o '[^ ]*%')"

# convert perc to int
pint="${perc/.*}"

# number of # to plot
nums="$(echo "$pint /2" | bc)"

# output
echo -e ""
echo -e "   completed: $perc"
echo -ne "   "
for i in $(seq $nums); do echo -n '#'; done
echo -e ""
echo -e "  |----.----|----.----|----.----|----.----|----.----|"
echo -e "  0%       20%       40%       60%       80%       100%"
echo -e ""
tail -1 run.log
echo -e ""
```

Thanks for your help, guys!

Comment: I attached the final script below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

based on your example

```
grep -o '[^ ]*%'
```

should give what you want.

Comment: That works fine and looks like an easy and elegenat way! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can extract % from below command:

```
tail -n 1 run.log | grep -o -P '[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?(?=%)'
```

Explanation:

```
grep options:
-o : Print only matching string.
-P : Use perl style regex

regex parts:
[0-9]* : Match any number, repeated any number of times.
(\.[0-9]*)? : Match decimal point, followed by any number of digits. 
              ? at the end of it => optional. (this is to take care of numbers without fraction part.)
(?=%)  :The regex before this must be followed by a % sign. (search for "positive look-ahead" for more details.)
```

Comment: That works! Great! Could you please shortly explain the regexp?

Comment: Thanks anishsane for give me this short introduction into perl style regex!

Comment: If it works & solves your purpose, upvote it & accept the answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to isolate the progress after the first `comma (,)` in your file. ie.you want the characters between `,` and `%`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve your goal. I would prefer using *cut* several times as it is easy to read.

```
cut -f1 -d'%' | cut -f2 -d',' | cut -f2 -d' '
```

After first *cut*:

```
 Time to finish 2d 15h, 42.5
```

After second (note space):

```
 42.5
```

And the last one just to get rid of space, the final result:

```
42.5
```